# How to batch combine single tif files to multipage tifs

Tags: bash, images, merge, tiff

I have folders with photos in each in tiff format.

What I am looking to do is merge the images in each folder and name the output with the folder name it resides in.

I have folders with images loaded in each:

1. ( photo1.tiff, photo2.tiff, photo3.tiff, photo4.tiff)
2. (photoa.tiff, photob.tiff,)

I've tried to merge all the tiffs in the individual folders using the script below.

```
#!/bin/bash dirs=$(find . -type f -name "*.tiff" | xargs dirname |sort -u) r d in $dirs; do #ls $d/*.tiff # just debug info, should list all desired tiffs #echo $(cut -d/ -f3 <<<$d) # debug info, should be desired output file name convert $d/*.tiff $(cut -d/ -f3 <<<$d).tiff done
```

When I run the script I get a single tiff which combines all photos from all folders.
How can I batch convert subfolders that contain multiple images (TIFFs) and make a single tiff in each folder and give the image the name of its folder? Any suggestions greatly welcomed.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi David, I've tried to narrow it down and make it a bit more friendly. Thanks to music also who helped in edit it a bit more friendlier than even i've written. Hopefully I've made the changes to suit. Many thanks. J

Comment: Much better. I've also added [tag:bash] and reopened.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution to this problem.

https://www.cvisiontech.com/reference/file-conversion/tiff-batch-converter.html

To work it you will need to refer to the instruction manual. You run a cmd prompt and apply ur conversion script from there